# How to create a Karaoke-style lyrics player on Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Hello I'm starting in flutter and I set out as a personal project to create a karaoke style app, I'm using a CupertinoPicker to auto scroll the lyrics with form advance the song.
In this video is how it is currently: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxLOEytLF9s

I have the following information:

```
[
{
    phrase: "Fisrt phrase",
    startAt: timeInMiliseconds
},
{
    phrase: "Second phrase",
    startAt: timeInMiliseconds
}
```

I would like to know how I can make the animation of how the color of the letter is changing as the phrase progresses, the duration of the animation would be the difference between the start time of the current phrase and the time at which the next sentence begins. And how can I add a character that is animated.

Something like what you see in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOchBDkNZg8

How could I do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for that. You can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_lyric that support lyric file .lrc format